# Running Multiple Languages on Arduino

Tags: python

This is mostly a conceptual question. Is it possible to have two scripts running on an Arduino, where one is a Julia script, and one is a Python script or something like that?

Comment: [julialang.org](http://julialang.org/) refers to  “Julia’s LLVM-based just-in-time compiler”.   If you get LLVM bitcode from the compiler, it might be possible to put that through the [AVR Backend To LLVM](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=LLVM-AVR-Backend-In-Works) to get an assembly language or ELF file to download to an AVR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically no, because you can't run either Julia *or* Python, let alone both together.

Bear in mind also what an Arduino is (what most of them are, anyway): a low (computational) power microprocessor with a tiny amount of RAM. No operating system, no multi-tasking. Not in the same league as, for example, a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Thats a pretty straight forward answer lol! Thanks. I'm not surprised by Python because it's interpretted, but Julia compiles into machine code, so I thought that would at least work.

Comment: And basically correct one. There is ofcourse possibility to run interpreted langs on Arduino, even python ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114916/is-there-a-way-to-compile-python-code-onto-an-arduino-uno ), there are some OS for it too and it can use external memory somehow, but Arduino is better used for other tasks, where you need small platform for some small things, which should be lightweigth and fast and usually solve just one or two tasks.  Cars, motocycles, bycicles and walks are also best fit for different tasks :)

Comment: What about Arduino DUE? It's an ARM based board.